# My GraphQLmuatation is not saving to dynamodb

Tags: aws-appsync

This is my schema QWS GraphQL schema

```
type Mutation {
createPost(input: postInput): Post
}

type Post {
id: ID!
title: String!
}

type Query {
singlePost(id: ID!): Post
getPost: [Post]
}

input postInput {
id: ID
title: String
}

schema {
query: Query
mutation: Mutation
}
```

When I query(add new data) the mutatin with following code

```
mutation addPost {
  createPost(input: {
    title: "Test title"
  }) {
title
  }
}
```

It's not saving to db and the result showing is

```
{
  "data": {
    "createPost": null
  }
}
```

What is the reason and how to solve this

Same happening for list all data query in other API

Comment: Can you provide the resolver code?

Comment: Got... thanks @Neill. Resolver was not set.